# Как отключить меню пуск, вот чтоб его прям вообще не было? Python

Tags: python

Вся суть вопроса в названии...

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтоб убрать панель задач, и большинство функций, нужно просто убить процесс explorer.exe